# Calculus Integrals

Tags: calculus

I found this problem, but I am not quite sure how to solve it. It says:

> Express $\int \log(\log x)dx$ in terms of $\int \frac {1}{ \log x} dx$

Some help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Integrate by parts:
$$\int \log (\log x)dx = x\log(\log x)-\int\frac{1}{\log x}dx.$$